# How to run python script using subprocess from another delivery

Tags: python, subprocess

I need to run another python script which generating data in my script I current working with. I use `subprocess` to run it:

```
cmd = 'python /home/usr/script.py arg1 arg2 arg3'
subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True)
```

But have a problem. Previous script generate few directories in 'current directory', it means in directory it was run in. And I can't modify previous script, cause it's not mine. How to set current directory to dir where I want to get data? `\n`
Another small problem is that when I run `subprocess.Popen()` my script doesn't end. Should I run it in another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the best way is to use `subprocess.call` instead (waits & terminates, `Popen` without the relevant `wait()` may create a zombie process) and use the `cwd=` parameter to specify current dir for the subprocess:

```
cmd = ['python','/home/usr/script.py','arg1','arg2','arg3']
return_code = subprocess.call(cmd, cwd="/some/dir")
```

(also pass the command as a list, and drop `shell=True`, you don't need it here)

Comment: I find `os.chdir()` method as a solution, but your path as method argument is better. Ty for help.

Comment: yes,`os.chdir()` should be avoided because it changes current directory for current process (and also other threads if there are some)